# Strange Shared Preference on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I have 2 `Fragments`. `1st` is for calculation while the `2nd` is for settings.

I save the settings using `SharedPreference.Editor.commit()` on `onPause()` method. No problem so far with the saving. The problem I am facing is retrieving the `SharedPreference` value on my `1st Fragment`. I retrieved the value every time I pressed the `count` button. For the 1st time, the values I am getting are the ones before change (which is the problem I am facing), I will only get my saved value when retrieving/pressing the `count` button for the 2nd time or more.

And I try to change the settings and then press `home` button to terminate the app from outside (which triggers `onPause` method) and when I reopened the settings, the values did change to my defined settings. So, I am sure the settings did saved when `onPause` is triggered.

I wonder what is going wrong here. Any helps is much appreciated.

As requested, this is my saving code on my `SettingFragment` :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveToPref();
    }

public void saveToPref() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mysettings", 0);
        Editor edit = settings.edit();
        edit.putString("begin", String.valueOf(ibegin)).putString("end", String.valueOf(iend)).commit();
    }
```

Comment: @SherifelKhatib have it added

Comment: 1. `Are you sure the return value of commit() is true?`. 2. `Are you sure that ibegin and iend are always up-to-date?`

Comment: I assume you are saving old values the first time.

Comment: Yes, since the values I retrieved when pressing the `count` button for the 2nd time on `1st fragment` is the values I saved. The problem is the 1st time I retrieved, the values are the ones before save.

Comment: try to go the 1st time and change values to V1 then go 2nd time change to V2. When you check the values, you get V1 or V2?

Comment: Ok, let's say the current default value is 0, I change to 1 and go back to `1st fragment` and calculate I get the 0 value, and then I go to `2nd fragment` and change it to 2, and then back to `1st fragment` and calculate I get the 1 value. and without going back to `2nd` I calculate and the value now become 2.

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the SharedPreferences again in 1st Fragment? Check that code again! I think you are loading them in onPause instead of onResume

Comment: Yes, sure. Nope, I'm loading the `SharedPreference` on `onClick` of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found my problem. The problem is that `onPause()` is triggered only when I start another activity (I started an activity `onClick` of `Button count`). I changed my code to trigger the `saveToPref()` by overriding `onPageSelected` of my `ViewPager` and on `backPressed` of my `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `SharedPreferences` object somewhere else, and do it once - maybe in `onCreate`. The reason why you're not seeing the change is because a different instance of `SharedPreferences` is opened somewhere, with the same constructor, and multiple instances of these do not automatically resolve/merge. While you're at it, initialize the Editor `edit` instance along with `settings`.

Comment: I have tried to initialize it on my `MainActivity` and use setter and getter to get the `SharedPreference` but still have the problem.